# Making a help command with select-menu discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am using discord_slash.utils.manage_components for help commands. I am trying to create help command in python.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/908053630425366538/940270195040198696/unknown.png

This my code

```py
from discord_slash.utils.manage_components import create_select, create_select_option, create_actionrow

    @cog_ext.cog_slash(name="help", description="Get the list of commands")
    async def _help(self, ctx: SlashContext):
        select = create_select(
            options=[
                create_select_option("General", value="General", emoji="", default=True),
                create_select_option("Fun", value="Fun", emoji="", default=False),
                create_select_option("Admin", value="Admin", emoji="️", default=False)
            ],
            placeholder="Choose your option",
            min_values=1,  # the minimum number of options a user must select
            max_values=1  # the maximum number of options a user can select
        )
        action_row = create_actionrow(select)

        # Embed general
        embed1 = discord.Embed(
            title=
            "<:mephisto:940249600969801748> **Mephisto General Commands**",
            color=0xDC0000)
        embed1.add_field(name="`/ping`", value="Return websocket ping")
        embed1.add_field(name="`/invite`",
                                value="Invite bot to your server")
        embed1.add_field(name="`/user-info [member]`",
                                value="Get a someone info")
        embed1.add_field(
            name="`/weather-info [city]`",
            value="Tell us the weather of the city you want to know")
        embed1.add_field(name="`/donut`",
                                value="Send ASCII art donut spinning")
        embed1.add_field(name="`/server-info`", value="Server info")
        embed1.add_field(name="`/info`",
                                value="Get information about Mephisto bot")

        # Embed fun
        embed2 = discord.Embed(
            title=
            "<:mephisto:940249600969801748> **Mephisto Fun Commands**",
            color=0xDC0000)
        embed2.add_field(name="`/joke`", value="Get a random joke")
        embed2.add_field(name="`/meme`",
                                value="Get a random meme")

        # Embed admin
        embed3 = discord.Embed(
            title=
            "<:mephisto:940249600969801748> **Mephisto Admin Commands**",
            color=0xDC0000)
        embed3.add_field(name="`/clear [amount]`", value="Clear messages")
        embed3.add_field(name="`/ban`",
                                value="Ban someone user")
        embed3.add_field(name="`/Kick`",
                                value="Kick someone user")

        pages = [embed1]
        page0 = [embed1]
        page1 = [embed2]
        page2 = [embed3]
        total_pages = [page0, page1, page2]
        page = 0

        category="General "

        message = await ctx.send(embed=pages[page], components=[action_row])

        while True:
          try:
              interaction = await self.bot.wait_for(
                  'interaction',
                  check=lambda inter: inter.message.id == message.id,
                  timeout=60
              )
          except asyncio.TimeoutError:
              for row in action_row:
                  row.disable_components()
              return await message.edit(content='Timed out!', components=action_row)

          if isinstance(interaction.component, create_select):
              action_row[0][0].default=False
              
              create_select_option.default=True
              pages=page1
              page=0
              try:
                action_row[1][0].disabled=True
                action_row[1][1].disabled=True
                print("check")
              except:
                pass  
              await interaction.edit_origin(embed=pages[page], components = action_row)
```

Select option doesn't working

I couldn't understand what is the problem. Someone help me to solve this problem.